# "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before" in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I met a problem in Xcode. And my problem was similar to this one: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40121-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before.html

So I want to know how to solve the problem in the link above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before...in Objective C ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246509/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks your link. It helps.
@Peter Sorry,for some reason,I can't paste my code here. But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason for this error is using a class name that is unknown at this point. Please double-check all your `#import` statements to see if you're missing any.

**Edit**: If this appears in a header file, you should probably use `@class` instead of `#import`, but make sure the corresponding `#import` exists in the .m file.