# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before…

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am not sure why I got this error in the DetailViewController.. the header is included no spelling mistake. tried cleaning the project and build it

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Conversation.h"
#import "Login.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailMessageViewController : UIViewController<RKObjectLoaderDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  MHLazyTableImagesDelegate> {
    DetailViewController * detailViewController;  //error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before
    UITableView * tableView;
    NSMutableArray * messages;
    MHLazyTableImages* lazyImages;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * messages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController * detailViewController;

@end
```

Comment: It may be useful to post snippets of the three header files you import.

Comment: From the **Related** sidebar, among others: [error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before...in Objective C ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246509/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have circularly dependent imports.  Is the header file for `DetailMessageViewController` also included in `DetailViewController.h` or `Login.h` or `Conversation.h`?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, one of these.  I hate these.

Most likely, it is because of the protocols are not declared (or misspelled).  Or it is because there is a syntax error in a header that causes the compiler to fail to close an expression or scope.   Or it could be a syntax error near where the header file was imported in the .m file.

In any case, a pain in the butt.   What you can do, though, is grab the compiler command line and put -E in it;  that'll cause the compiler to precompile everything and dump exactly what it was going to compile into what should be the .o (you can change that name, too).  Then, if you look at where the above line of code falls, the line causing the error should be nearby, even if from a different header

Comment: the issue is that I have successfully done this with other UIViewController, i.e: adding the DetailViewController * detailViewController to other UIViewController subclass, this only happens for the class DetailMessageViewController

Comment: Then that sounds like there is a syntax error in the .m file;  are you #importing headers in the .m file exactly like the others?