# Objective-C expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've searched but I did not get with the solution. I have a class which inherits from NSObject. It has the following imports:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Constants.h"
#import "CommonProtocols.h"
#import "SomeClass.h"

@interface SomeComtroller : NSObject
```

Than I have SomeClass.

```
 #import "SomeController.h"

 @interface SomeClass : NSObject
 {
     SomeController *myController; // ERROR!
 } 
 @end
```

However, I can't define SomeController in SomeClass. It gives me the error, I really want to have a property of SomeController in SomeClass, and have in the controller a property of someClass.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before...in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246509/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency — SomeClass.h imports SomeController.h, which imports SomeClass.h, which imports…

The solution is to move the imports into the implementation files, and just forward-declare the other classes you're using with the `@class` directive (e.g. `@class SomeController;` in SomeClass.h).

Comment: Hmm, never used _@class_ before. Can you write how it would be please?

Comment: @marcg11: I did. It's just `@class ` + the name of whatever class you want to declare. For example, in SomeClass.h, above the class declaration, you'd write `@class SomeController;`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Why can't I access to the properties of SomeController inside SomeClass? I have assigned in the init.

Comment: @marcg11: It's hard to understand what you're describing — "can't access" could mean many different things. Comments aren't very good for explaining things, so it's probably better to ask another question with the details.