# Xcode refuses to acknowledge well-written code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before…in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246509/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-in-objective-c)

I honestly don't know what's wrong, here. This code has worked before, and all of the related files are well-written and compile on their own (even the respective `.m` file), but there is one `.h` file in an O-C project of mine in which Xcode constantly throws the same compile errors. Sometimes multiple times per line, sometimes only once, but always on the `useCommand` variable. Below is a screenshot and copy/pasted code of the entire affected `.h` file, which is *the ONLY file that doesn't compile*. The program runs perfectly when I comment out every reference to `useCommand`, but when I uncomment them, this happens, again. I even went so far as to create a new project and copy/paste all the code over into new files, and this error still appears. When I move the `useCommand` references to new lines, Xcode's errors follow it. **Does anybody know what is going on with Xcode?** I'm pretty sure it's not a mistake of mine, as I've quadruple-checked my code to be sure it's all proper, and I've cleaned the targets several times.

[image: Xcode refuses to acknowledge useCommand]

### Classes

---

### Minecraftia.h

```
//
//  Minecraftia.h
//  TextCraft
//
//  Created by Supuhstar on 4/3/12.
//  Copyright 2012 Blue Husky Programming. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Command.h"
#import "HelpCommand.h"
#import "UseCommand.h"
#import "GetCommand.h"
#import "LookCommand.h"
#import "IO.h"

@interface Minecraftia : NSObject
{
    HelpCommand *helpCommand;
    UseCommand *useCommand;
    GetCommand *getCommand;
    LookCommand *lookCommand;
}
-(id)init;

/**
 * If none has already been created, creates a static instance of Minecraftia
 * 
 * Returns the same instance of Minecraftia each time
 */
+(Minecraftia *)sharedInstance;

/**
 * Turns the given string into a command
 * If no matching command is found, nil is returned
 */
-(Command *)toCommand:(NSString *)input;

/**
 * The main method of the game, wherein all interactions happen
 */
-(void)play;

/**
 * Returns a random message to be used as splash text when the program is started
 */
-(NSString *)getASplash;

/**
 * Returns an NSArray of all the available commands
 */
-(NSArray*)getRegisteredCommands;

@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) HelpCommand *helpCommand;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) UseCommand *useCommand;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) GetCommand *getCommand;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) LookCommand *lookCommand;
@end
```

### HelpCommand.h

```
//
//  HelpCommand.h
//  TextCraft
//
//  Created by Student4 on 4/9/12.
//  Copyright 2012 Blue Husky Programming. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Command.h"
#import "Minecraftia.h"

@interface HelpCommand : Command {

}

@end
```

### HelpCommand.m

```
//
//  HelpCommand.m
//  TextCraft
//
//  Created by Student4 on 4/9/12.
//  Copyright 2012 Blue Husky Programming. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HelpCommand.h"


@implementation HelpCommand
-(bool)execute:(NSArray *)info
{
    NSString *helpString = @"Here are all the available commands:\n";
    NSArray *commands = [[Minecraftia sharedInstance] getRegisteredCommands];
    for(int i=0, l=[commands count]; i < l; i++)
    {
        helpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t> %@", [helpString stringByAppendingString:[[[commands objectAtIndex:i] class] triggerText]]];
    }
    MyLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n", helpString]);
    return true;
}



+(NSString *)triggerText
{
    static NSString *triggerText = @"HELP";
    return triggerText;
}
@end
```

Comment: **Do not post screenshots of code**. Copy and paste the actual code text into your question so we can (1) actually read it without squinting, and (2) easily compile it if need be. Posting screenshots of source code is *almost* as useless as not putting in any code at all and does not help any of your potential answerers. Use pictures only for things that are not text. Seriously, please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Show us the content of `HelpCommand.h`. I bet it's broken.  Also what compiler (and version) are you using?  You don't need to declare `- (id)init` as you inherit that method from `NSObject` so it's already not so *well written*.

Comment: @Insilico Sorry about that; I thought it was best,a s it gives you the meta information such as "I have all these files in these groups", and "This is how the error looks on this line", etc. The requested code has been posted.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know I don't need to declare `-(id)init`, but my professor required it, so I got into the habit of doing that for all my headers. I'll be trying to get back out of it :/

Comment: Hm...move the `#import "Minecraftia.h"` from `HelpCommand.h` to `HelpCommand.m`?

Comment: @aroth That didn't change the compiler output in any way

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1246509/1047258). I suppose that it's pretty much the same. Hope it helps

Comment: @Novarg Thank you! That fixed it. Now on to more strange compile errors -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @class instead of import unless you absolutely need the header, and then move the import to your .m file.  Right now you're putting the compiler in a loop, Minecraftia.h is importing UseCommand.h and UseCommand.h is importing Minecraftia.h.

Should look like this:

```c
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "IO.h"

@class Command, HelpCommand, UseCommand, GetCommand, LookCommmand;

@interface Minecraftia : NSObject
{
    HelpCommand *helpCommand;
    UseCommand *useCommand;
    GetCommand *getCommand;
    LookCommand *lookCommand;
}

/* .... */

@end
```